# primefaces commandbutton ajax submit works as a non-ajax submit

Tags: java, ajax, primefaces, liferay, commandbutton

I'm using primefaces 3.5 and I want to update de value of an object using p:commandButton with ajax, but when I click on the p:commandButton the form submits entirely as a non-ajax submit. I tried with immediate=true, ajax="true" (but I read that this option is the default) partial-submit="true" but nothing, the button refresh all the page instead of just the asignarUA component.

Note: this is a liferay (6.2 CE) portlet.

This is part of the code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"  
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"  
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head></h:head>
<h:body>
<h:form>
    <p:commandButton onclick="asignarUADlg.show()" update=":asignarUA" title="Asignar" value="Asignar">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{solicitud }" target="#{mailboxView.solicitud}"/>
    </p:commandButton>                                                
</h:form>


<p:dialog id="asignarUA" widgetVar="asignarUADlg" modal="true" header="Asignar Unidades Administrativas" width="530" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade">
    <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <h:outputLabel for="dependencia" value="Dependencia: " />
        <h:outputText value="#{mailboxView.solicitud.nombreDependencia}" rendered="#{not empty mailboxView.solicitud}" />
        <p:separator />

        <p:commandButton value="Enviar" ajax="false" actionListener="#{mailboxView.asignar}" update=":messages2"/>
        <p:commandButton value="Cancelar" onclick="asignarUADlg.hide()" type="button"/>
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the button presenting the problem? Note that all the three <p:commandButton> are not ajax. <p:commandButton> is not ajax true by default, so if you want an ajax behavior on it you must manually set ajax=true on the desired button.

Comment: According to the primefaces show case ajax=true is the default value. http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/button/commandButton.xhtml Anyway I also tried with ajax=true but the behavior is the same. Greetings.

Comment: Your code has an error on line 5: `</p:form>` should be `</h:form>`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had to upgrade my PrimeFaces version to 5.3 and it works. The only thing that I had to change was the process attribute:

```
<p:commandButton process="@this :dialogContent" update=":dialogContent" onclick="PF('asignarUADlg').show()" title="Asignar" value="Asignar">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{solicitud }" target="#{mailboxView.solicitud}"/>
</p:commandButton>
```

Comment: I would rather use `oncomplete` to make sure the dialog is shown after the ajax update.

Answer (score 2):

Your first `p:commandButton` is showing the dialog and then immediately hiding it again. This is also causing the page to blink, and I think you have mistaken this blinking for a non-ajax submit. When you click your the `p:commandButton`, `dialog.show()` is called and the dialog is shown. Then the `update=":dialogId"` code runs* and sends an ajax request to the server to re-render the dialog. Since the server does not know that `dialog.show()` has been called on the client, the server thinks that the dialog should still be in its default state: hidden. So the partial response that comes back resets the dialog to its initial state and hides the dialog again.

**The solution is to update the content of the dialog instead of the whole dialog.** For your particular example, you should add an `id` to your second `h:form` and update that from your *Asignar* button:

```
<h:form>
    <p:commandButton onclick="asignarUADlg.show()" update=":dialogContent"
    title="Asignar" value="Asignar">

<!-- ... -->

<p:dialog id="asignarUA" widgetVar="asignarUADlg" modal="true"
    header="Asignar Unidades Administrativas" width="530" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade">
    <h:form id="dialogContent" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<!-- ... -->
```

*The `update` attribute causes the `p:commandButton` to render code to send an ajax request in its `onclick` attribute. So the ajax code is literally called right after `dialog.show()`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I just try it and the behavior is the same. But I realized of another thing, is not a blink what it does after showing the dialog is the whole page refreshing because even the url change it and appears with a lot of parameters like a GET petition. It is very weird because I try the same code in another clean project and it works. I don't know if is something with liferay or with my headers.

Comment: Is your `p:commandButton` `ajax="false"`? You should make sure that the button is performing an ajax request. Also I would recommend `diff`-ing the config of your two projects (the working one and the failing one) to see if any config differs.

Comment: No, is not ajax="false" I also tried the comparison between the working and the not working code, but nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<p:commandButton onclick="asignarUADlg.show()" update=":asignarUA:dialogContent"
title="Asignar" value="Asignar">
```